# json_encode Array with int index

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to encode a similar Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 393922111111
    [1] => 393433333333
    [2] => 393555555555
)
```

with json_encode.

I'm getting this:

```
["393922111111","393433333333","393555555555"]
```

that seems not correct.
I.e. i put it into a

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" id="destinatariSMS" name="destinatariSMS" value="';
     echo json_encode($destinatariSMS);
 echo '" />'.PHP_EOL;
```

and in next page 'll receive only first bracket.

Could you gimme some hint? Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use `intval()` to force them to an integer instead of a string.

Comment: Those numbers exceed the 32bit integer limit in 32bit PHP, so they HAVE to encoded as strings.

Comment: Or simply use single quotes for your `value=''` so that you don't have double quotes inside double quotes.

Comment: And try looking at the HTML you're generating; your JSON includes quotes, and you're using quotes to define attributes in your tags. You'll want to escape the HTML somehow....

Comment: On 64bit systems and with PHP 5.3.3 you can use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag to get actual integers. The proper escaping answers are however what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do elementary mistake by not escaping your encoded json correctly prior putting is as INPUT value. Some characters, including `"` needs to be quoted (`"` => `&quot;`) to "work" with HTML. So valid code should be:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="destinatariSMS" name="destinatariSMS" value="';
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($destinatariSMS));
echo '" />'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thank you. After several hours... i'm making this terrific mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you output to html, you should use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to encode your output so that it cannot break the html:

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" id="destinatariSMS" name="destinatariSMS" value="';
     echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($destinatariSMS));
 echo '" />'.PHP_EOL;
```

In your case the quotes in your json close the `value` attribute.